# cannot use find elements by link text in python selenium

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Login</button>
```

I would like to click the `Login` button, here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get()
driver.find_element("link text", "Login")
```

the result is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Login"}
```

can you please help me to figure it out? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to a URL
driver.get("URL of the web page")

# Find the "Login" button by its class name
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn")

# Click the button
login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

in selenium4:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
driver.find_element(By.Link_Text,'Login').click()
```

not in selenium4:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Login').click()
```

I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

`link text` or `Partial link text` only support for `<a>` element. It doesn't support `button` element.

Instead link text, use either `xpath` or `css selector`

```
driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[text()='Login']")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Login']").click()
```

You need to import below library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```